# In spite of the options, the screen locks after X minutes

Tags: screen, lock

The OS Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal) is installed on my computer. I want my computer never locks the monitor's screen. For that I chose the item "never" in the option "Lock the screen after...". But it doesn't work. What should I do to improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's the same problem I had it's xscreensaver timeout being set to 6000 that's the problem.

Try running `xset s 0 0` from the command line, this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Open **system settings** and select **brightness and lock**

Slide the button below **Lock** to off.

[image: Screen Lock settings Ubuntu]

Comment: I did it. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago and found the solution by running the following command in terminal:

```
xset s off -dpms
```

This will disable the screensaver and the display power management.

You can put it in Start-up Programs if you want.